# Can the solution to this equation be written as the root of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, roots

While thinking about [a question on another Stack](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-is-it-easier-to-escape-the-solar-system-than-get-to-mercury-or-the-sun), I ended up trying to solve the following equation for $a$:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{a} - \frac{2}{a+1}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{a}} + 1 - \sqrt{2 - \frac{2}{a+1}} = \sqrt{2} - 1
$$
Numerically, it seems that there is a solution at $a \approx 0.490981...$.  However, neither I nor Mathematica was able to get this equation into a form where it is obviously an algebraic number.

Can the above solution be written as the root of some polynomial?  If so, which one?  If not, why not?  (It would be surprising to me that what looks like an algebraic equation, involving square roots and simple rational functions, does not have an solution in the algebraic numbers, even for some polynomial of high degree.)

(For those who are curious: $a$ corresponds to the radius, in AU, for which it is more costly to get into a circular orbit at that radius than it is to leave the solar System.)

Comment: Sure, but it isn't going to be pretty.  Multiply both sides by $\sqrt {a(a+1)}$ then isolate all the terms with a radical dependent on $a$ in them on one side and square.  That should get you down to one term with $\sqrt {a(a+1)}$ or the like so you can isolate and  square again.  You'll still need numerical methods to find the roots.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Is the $+1$ on the LHS under the radical?

Comment: @Moo:  It is not.

Comment: It's an algebraic irrational equation. An algebraic irrational equation is zeroing equation of an algebraic function. All solutions of such an equation are algebraic therefore. Each algebraic irrational equation can be transformed to a polynomial equation. The solution set of the polynomial equation contains the solution set of the algebraic irrational equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [a root of the quartic equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2048+sqrt%282%29+x%5E4+-+3072+x%5E4+%2B+6656+sqrt%282%29+x%5E3+-+8192+x%5E3+%2B+3072+sqrt%282%29+x%5E2+-+6208+x%5E2+-+1536+sqrt%282%29+x+%2B+2944+x+-+64+%3D+0):

`2048 sqrt(2) x^4 - 3072 x^4 + 6656 sqrt(2) x^3 - 8192 x^3 + 3072 sqrt(2) x^2 - 6208 x^2 - 1536 sqrt(2) x + 2944 x - 64 = 0`

Nicely formatted:

$$ 2048 \sqrt2 x^4 - 3072 x^4 + 6656 \sqrt2 x^3 - 8192 x^3 + 3072 \sqrt2 x^2 - 6208 x^2 - 1536 \sqrt2 x + 2944 x - 64 = 0
$$

Synopsis:

Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{a(a+1)}$.

Use the substitution $y = a + 1/2$

Then rearrange the equation such that only one side contains radicals of the variable $y$. Then square both sides.

Repeat the step above.

Back substitute and simplify.

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3):

Using Maple's Groebner Basis package, we find that $a$ satisfies the equation
$$
256a^8-1024a^7-2080a^6+3520a^5+3105a^4-4060a^3+1158a^2-92a+1=0
$$
Here's the Maple code . . .

[image]

Comment: What is the syntax used?

Comment: I'll edit to show the Maple code.

Comment: But can there be a systematic way for proving that solutions to such expressions are algebraic?

Comment: Well, it's clear that by appropriate iterated squaring, you don't lose any roots (but typically you gain some).